# How to make a python script send me a dm via discord if x happens within the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I run a small python bot that requires data from Github. To not get blocked by Github I download the data and automatically update it every week. I would like to get notified via a discord dm in case the bot couldn't connect to Github and update it's data.

I already have a check for if the bot couldn't update it's data and now all I need is that the bot sends me a dm. Because of schedule I run the automatic updater in a thread.

The problem I face is that this results in: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'` in the `guild = await bot.fetch_guild(GUILD_ID)` line and I don't see why it doesn't work. I already created a little test bot to test if the `notify_on_no_respond` function works and if triggered by a command from discord it works perfectly.

Full Error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (start_updater):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "\\StationDS216\home\Projects\Python\Discord Bots\test lab\Bot_auto_updater.py", line 7, in start_updater
    Thread_Auto_Updater = auto_updater(
  File "\\StationDS216\home\Projects\Python\Discord Bots\test lab\Bot_auto_updater.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.data['Bot'].problem_occured()
  File "\\StationDS216\home\Projects\Python\Discord Bots\test lab\Bot_main.py", line 70, in problem_occured
    asyncio.run(notify_on_no_respond())
  File "C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "\\StationDS216\home\Projects\Python\Discord Bots\test lab\Bot_main.py", line 74, in notify_on_no_respond
    guild = await bot.fetch_guild(GUILD_ID)
  File "C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 1188, in fetch_guild
    data = await self.http.get_guild(guild_id)
  File "C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 192, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'
```

If anyone knows how to fix this problem I would love to hear it. Thanks in advance.

If you need anything from me to help you help me ask and I will try to provide it.

This replicates the code I use but for some reason creates a different error: (you will have to provide your own token etc. in an .env)

```
# Bot_Game_main.py
import Bot_Game_auto_updater
import os
import discord
import threading
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
MY_ID = os.getenv('DISCORD_MY_ID')
GUILD_ID = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD_ID')
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')


class maintainer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start_thread(self, Bot_Game):
        threading.Thread(target=Bot_Game_auto_updater.start_updater,
                         args=(Bot_Game,), daemon=True).start()

    def problem_occured(self):
        asyncio.run(notify_on_no_respond())


async def notify_on_no_respond():
    guild = await bot.fetch_guild(GUILD_ID)
    user = await guild.fetch_member(MY_ID)
    await user.send('a problem occured')

Bot_Game = maintainer()
Bot_Game.start_thread(Bot_Game)
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

```
# Bot_Game_auto_updater.py
def start_updater(Bot_Game):
    Thread_Auto_Updater = auto_updater(Bot_Game)


class auto_updater(object):
    def __init__(self, Bot_Game):
        Bot_Game.problem_occured()
```

Comment: Wait. Why do you have both a `Bot` and a `Client`? Please see [ask] and [mre]. Please [edit] your question to include the part of code that has `<something>.request` in it. And do you have [the necessary intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html)? Also, I think some essential parts of your discord.py-related code are missing.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder I simply followed a (outdated?) tutorial on how to set up a bot and that one used `Bot` and `Client`. I just realized that I don't actually use `Client` for anything. The question about the intents is actually not too bad. When I first created the bot I didn't need an intent to check for members so I might actually not have that, will try to check that if I figure out how. This should be all necessary discord.py code for the problem, the rest are simple commands that work on their own. About the edit: the error happens in the `guild =` line, there is no `request` in the code.

Comment: Quick follow up one the question about intents: the test bot I wrote (the one that worked) used the same token etc. So as far as my understanding goes that should mean that the bot should have the required intents.
Also if turned into a command (through `@bot.command(name='dm')`) the command worked, so the problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the *full* traceback of the error. As well the question should have a [mcve] (emphasis on *minimal*)

Comment: I'm having a hard time creating a minimal example that replicates the error (it gets a different error), I will try to figure out what the problem is and come back to this once I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all to you main Problem: I would recommend not using that code, there is a way better way to do so with the [get_user](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get%20user#discord.Client.get_user) method:

```
from discord.utils import get

user = await client.get_user(user_id)
```

To DM a user I use this code:

```
channel = await user.create_dm()
await channel.send("a problem occured")
```

Hope this helped :D

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the late reply. I tried your "user = await ..." and got a "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'" error. I tried changing get_user to fetch_user but got the same results (I'm sure the ID is correct).